# How to clone a node without translations

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a site with multiple language. Assume I have a node (nid = 1) with **origin languages is en** and **translate to es**. And I clone this node with code:

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$nodeDuplicate = $node->createDuplicate();
$nodeDuplicate->save();
```

And I have a new node (nid = 2), and the new node have two content translate en, es same the node id 1.

But I don't want clone all content translate. **I only want to clone one language es or en**. So how can do that?

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion : use `->removeTranslation()` to get rid of the languages you don't want to be cloned.

Example to get rid of 'es language' so that we clone only the english version :

```
$langcodetoremove = 'es';
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1);
$node->removeTranslation($langcodetoremove);
$nodeDuplicate = $node->createDuplicate();
$nodeDuplicate->save();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I tried but I have problem when I want to clone language is not origin. In my case, I can not use removeTranslation for **en** because this is origin language.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new node with the field values retrieved from the (translated) node:

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$values = $node->getTranslation('es')->toArray();
// remove nid, uuid, vid and revision details from $values
$node_duplicate = Node::create($values);
$node_duplicate->save();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this way. I have to set $values['language'] to langue I want to clone. But I have problem with field paragraph. Because your way field type paragraph can't not duplicate.

Comment: Yes, paragraphs can only be referenced by a single node. You would have to clone the paragraphs as well.

Comment: Can you provide me with example? I had tried follow this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/kunicmarko20/d1fcb622bda26f9707f6ff96297f2090). But don't know map with your code to working.

Comment: The snippet is for a fixed field, a universal solution would need to iterate through fields and replace all paragraphs. Important is that you replace the paragraph id and the revision id, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236544/programmatically-append-multiple-paragraphs-to-entity-reference-field-on-node/236548#236548

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$nodeDuplicate = $node->createDuplicate();

$langcode = 'fr';  
$nodeDuplicate->removeTranslation($langcode);
$nodeDuplicate->save();
```

Comment: Help me clone content is not origin language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code for copy translation with all field types and all node types:

`<?php
  use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
  $exclude = [
    'nid', 
    'vid', 
    'revision_timestamp', 
    'revision_uid', 
    'revision_log', 
    'revision_default', 
    'revision_translation_affected', 
    'content_translation_source', 
    'content_translation_outdated', 
    'created', 
    'changed', 
    'default_langcode', 
    'uuid'
  ];
  $node = Node::load(NODE_ID);
  if (!empty($node->hasTranslation(LANGCODE))) {
    $node = $node->getTranslation(LANGCODE);
  }
  $node_type = $node->getType();
  $fields = $node->getFieldDefinitions('node', $node_type);
  $copyied_fields = [];
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
    $field_name = $field_definition->getName();
    if (!in_array($field_name, $exclude)) {
      $field_value = $node->$field_name->value;
      if (empty($field_value)) {
        $field_value = $node->$field_name->getValue();
      }
      $copyied_fields[$field_name] = $field_value;
      // Add body format.
      if ($field_name == 'body') {
        $copyied_fields['body'] = array(
          'value' => $node->body->value,
          'format' => 'full_html',
        );
      }
    }
  }
  $new_node = Node::create($copyied_fields);
  $new_node->save();`