# Set entity reference revision field value?

Tags: 8, entities, nodes

How do I set entity reference revision value for a field? I have two fields, field_test_entity_reference and field_test_entity_revision. field_test_entity_reference is of field type entity reference and field_test_entity_revision is of type entity reference revision. Both are referring to the same content type. I have created a node of this content type and its id is 7747. I am trying the below code and it sets value correctly for the field which is of type entity reference but not for entity revision version.

```
$node-field_test_entity_reference->target_id=7747;
$node-field_test_entity_revision->target_id=7747;
$node->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store also the revision id, see [Programmatically append multiple paragraphs to entity reference field on node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236544/programmatically-append-multiple-paragraphs-to-entity-reference-field-on-node).

Or simply set an entity, from which the field can get the data it needs in both cases:

```
$node->field_test_entity_reference->entity = $target_node;
$node->field_test_entity_revision->entity = $target_node;
$node->save();
```